# mkdir permissions do not correspond to umask (change depending on location)

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, umask, mkdir

Whenever I create new directories in my home (or its subdirectories) they do not have write permission, even though umask is set correctly. Files I make DO have write permission.

```
[mmanary@seqap33 ~]$ umask
0002
[mmanary@seqap33 ~]$ mkdir testDir
[mmanary@seqap33 ~]$ touch testFile
[mmanary@seqap33 ~]$ ls -l
dr-xr-x--- 2 mmanary mmanary  0 Apr 15 10:25 testDir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mmanary mmanary  0 Apr 15 10:26 testFile
```

If I switch to a shared group storage directory, then new directories DO have write permission. I can switch them with chmod easily, BUT when using tar, the new directory cannot be written in to so the tar fails with "Permission Denied". Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have read other suggested questions, but not seem to apply directly because they involve more complicated cases (other users involved). In case this helps:

```
[mmanary@seqap33 ~]$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: mmanary
# group: mmanary
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
```

Edit2: On advice from comments, my filesystem is NFS

Comment: What filesystem are you using for `$HOME`? (Run `mount | grep $(df -h "$HOME | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')` if you're not sure.)

Comment: Well that exact command doesn't work. I get two lines of output from awk (the second line being "1.5P"). If I just search for the first line (i.e. second from df) I get

    isilon12:/ifs/data/rd/home/mmanary on /home/mmanary type nfs (rw,addr=XXX.XX.XX.XXX)

Comment: @MicahManary put additional information in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talked to the infrastructure people, and the answer is that there are extended ACLs in place that act differently based on location, and that they were erroneously set.

Comment: Indeed ACLs are the most obvious way to set up a directory in which permissions of new files don't follow the umask of the creating process.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I have seen this kind of scenario is when the NFS share is exported from a Windows server running NFS for Windows services. The POSIX attributes demanded by the Unix/Linux world aren't mapped cleanly onto the NTFS attributes and the result is that permissions display one thing and (sometimes) act as another.

In our particular situation we spent a couple of weeks trying to resolve the situation and eventually erased the Windows system and installed a Linux-based system on the hardware.

Answer (score -1):

If the sticky bit chmod +s is set on the folder, the umask is overridden with the attributes of the folder owner. that is why you may be seeing inconsistent results between folders.

Comment: That's not the problem here.  The umask of `0002` means the directory should normally be created `drwxrwxr-x`, but it's got `dr-xr-x---`.